# What is the integral of this function on [0,1]?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

$f_n(x)=n$ for $0<x<\frac 1 n$ and $0$ for $x \geq \frac  1n$ on $(0,1)$

**I have been given a hint that it diverges but I do not know how.** could anyone explain this for me, please?

Also, does it matters on $[0,1]$ or $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear. 
$$\int_0^1 f_n=1$$
for all $n$. What diverges ? $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x\in (0,1]$ and to $\infty $ when $x=0$. In other words, $f_n\to 0$ almost everywhere. Now, $\int_0^1f_n\to 1$,
so what diverges ? Now, indeed, $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_0^1 f_n>\int_0^1\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n,$$
if this was implicitly your question.

Comment: why $f_{n}(x) = \infty$ when $x=0$?

Comment: To answer that, figure out: What is $f_n(0)$?